# DAX measure Last Quarter Sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to create DAX measure which calculates the sales of last quarter. I would like to see products with last quarter's sales. Say something like this:

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| Product | Sales of last quarter |
+---------+-----------------------+
| apple   |                    10 |
| banana  |                     5 |
| cherry  |                     8 |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

I feel that the solution might be a mixture of two filters:

- DATESQTD
- Range of dates

This is my best guess:

```
Sales_of_last_quarter =
VAR MaxDate =
    LASTNONBLANK(
        'Calendar'[Date],
        CALCULATE(
            [Sales]
        )
    )
VAR SalesByQuarter =
    CALCULATE(
        [Sales],
        DATESQTD( Calendar[Date] )
    )
VAR result =
    CALCULATE(
        SalesByQuarter,
        MaxDate
    )
RETURN
    result
```

Above measure works. However I wonder if it is possible to make it in one shot. This does not work:

```
Sales_of_last_quarter =
VAR MaxDate =
    LASTNONBLANK(
        'Calendar'[Date],
        CALCULATE(
            [Sales]
        )
    )

RETURN
SalesByQuarter =
    CALCULATE(
        [Sales],
        DATESQTD( Calendar[Date] ),
        MaxDate
    )
```

It does not work because MaxDate is single date (one day), but it should be a range of a quarter.

So the question is how to define the range of the last quarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [CALCULATETABLE](https://dax.guide/calculatetable/) to get [DATESQTD](https://dax.guide/datesqtd/) up to [LASTNONBLANK](https://dax.guide/lastnonblank/) date.

```
Sales of Last Quarter = 
CALCULATE (
    [Sales],
    CALCULATETABLE (
        DATESQTD ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
        LASTNONBLANK ( 'Calendar'[Date], [Sales] )
    )
)
```

Comment: Oh yes, it works but how? LASTNONBLANK returns only one date whereas DATESQTD returns range of about 90 days. How come it knows to calculate Sales for range of quarter and take the last such quarter. Why does it not return the common part of those two function ranges which would be the LASTNONBLANK one day?

Comment: This is quite a guess, but it looks like some time intelligence functions including DATESQTD is effectively applying REMOVEFILTERS behind the scenes before it finds the dates in the interest. I found this SQLBI article (https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/time-intelligence-in-power-bi-desktop/) is mentioning about that, but I couldn't find it is clearly stated in any other document.

Comment: Thank you. The mistery is still there. The REMOVEFILTERS would return all dates, DATESQTD shrinks all to 90 days, but LASTNONBLANK shrinks it further to 1 day. At least, that's what I might expect, wrongly, of course.

Comment: Suprisingly this measure works as well: `CALCULATE( [Sales], DATESQTD( Calendar[Date] ) )`

Comment: Yes, this should work, except that it may be BLANK at the grand total. Suppose that you have dates until December 31 in the Calendar table, and Sales records until June 30. What DATESQTD returns at the grand total is "October 1 to December 31", and there is no Sales records in this period. If this is the desired behavior, it is just fine. If not, above formula might be a good fine tuning.